# How to set the date of the date-time picker on page refresh or page change in angular4

Tags: angular, datetimepicker

I am using ng2-date time picker referred from -

https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-datetimepicker

Suppose i go to page-2 that is situated inside the  page-1 and you get page-2 only after searching the data via search-by-date  datetime pickers . And then i am in page-2 and cancel the page-2 and come back to the page-1 , the date-time picker resets. I tried to get back the same date again but to no avail (it might happen that my code implementation is not proper).does the date time picker resets itself once the page changes.And is there a way to get back the same date after page refresh or do the date variables in the code  are also reset .

So my question is - How to set its value to the same as before page change/refresh.
I tried to use [options] but to no avail -

code -

**transaction.component.html**

```
     <div class="form-group " >


                <angular2-date-picker 
    [options]="toDateTransaction"
                 title="Click to enter To Date and Time" 
    [(ngModel)]="date1" [settings]="settings1"
                [(ngModel)]="toDateTransaction"  
    formControlName="toDateTransaction"></angular2-date-picker>
            </div>
```

**transaction.component.ts**

```
export class TransactionComponent implements OnInit{

  date1: Date = new Date();
  settings1 = {
  bigBanner: true,
  timePicker: true,
  format: 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm',

   defaultOpen: false
  }


  ngOnInit() {

 this.toDateTransaction = this.shareData.toDateTransact;
 }

 searchByDate(data_fromDate, data_toDate,filterDataForSearch) {

   this.shareData.toDateTransact = this.dataToDate;

   this.toDateTransaction = this.shareData.toDateTransact;
  }
  }
```

Error -

```
 Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
 Can't bind to 'options' since it isn't a known property of 'angular2- 
  date-picker'.


    <angular2-date-picker title="Click to enter From Date and Time" 
    [ERROR ->][options]="fromDateTransaction"
                [(ngModel)]="date" [settings]="settings" 
    "): ng:///MasterSystemModule/TransactionComponent.html@52:84
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `options` `property` in that [date picker documentation](https://github.com/CuppaLabs/angular2-datetimepicker),

so use,

```
<angular2-date-picker title="Click to enter To Date and Time"  [settings]="settings1" [(ngModel)]="toDateTransaction">
</angular2-date-picker>
```

now, to get data on refresh, store data in **`Localstorage`**

```
 ngOnInit() {
    if(localStorage.getItem('date'))
    {
      this.toDateTransaction = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('date'));
    }

  }

 searchByDate(data_fromDate, data_toDate,filterDataForSearch) {

   this.shareData.toDateTransact = this.dataToDate;
   this.toDateTransaction = this.shareData.toDateTransact;
   localStorage.setItem('date', JSON.stringify(this.toDateTransaction))
 }
```

Comment: i don't know why, but unfortunately , this method is non-functional. sorry for that. When i do console.log on init, it shows the correct value in console, but then the date is refreshed

Comment: let us debug, any issue you are facing?

Comment: no... noo i am not  facing  anyother issue... other than this one

Comment: please do add `{{toDateTransaction}}` in your template and we ll check what  data is cmng

Comment: i did this --> <angular2-date-picker style="width:190px"  title="Click to enter To Date and Time" [(ngModel)]="date1" [settings]="settings1"
                    [(ngModel)]="toDateTransaction"  formControlName="toDateTransaction"></angular2-date-picker>
                    {{toDateTransaction}} ... and the data is that of refreshed current date-time....

Comment: you cannot have two `ngModel` for the same div

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171820/discussion-between-sravan-and-sucheta-shrivastava).